# How to get rid of vertical space before and behind the lists

Tags: spacing, lists, environments

I cannot get rid of the vertical space before and behind the lists. I have code like below:

```
\begin{list}{-}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}    
  \item First item
  \item Second item
\end{list}
```

Comment: I just had a similar problem, and setting various lengths to `0pt` didn't help. It turned out that latex was expanding vertical spacing to get a nice page break at the end of a paragraph (which, of course, is a good thing). Something to watch out for if you're trying these answers on something that's not a MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this at stackexchange where you originally posted (below). I tried the suggested use of `\setlength{tosep}{0pt} but don't know if it's what you want. It seems that that eliminates space *in between* list items but not before and after lists themselves, but I could be wrong. My solution below may be hackish (or maybe not...), but it leaves no space between a previous paragraph, the itemized list, the items themselves, or the following paragraph.

---

Itemize without itemizing...

```
Some text that is here and I want to see what it does. \\
  \indent$\bullet$\,first item \\
  \indent$\bullet$\,second item \\
Some text that is here and I want to see what it does.
```

Replace `$\bullet$` with whatever you want.

```
\indent- first item\\
\indent$\cdot$\,first item\\
\indent$\circ$\,first item\\
\indent$\ast$\,first item\\
```

The "-" seems to work fine with the whitespace as shown but the rest need the trailing `\,` which inserts a space between the math symbol and the next word. Without it there will be no space between the "bullet" and the text that follows.

Comment: Yes, it looks nice, but what about the list which has items longer than one line, I need to put continuing line indented as well - I commented the same on stackoverflow

Comment: Think I got it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210766/latex-vertical-space-before-and-behind-the-lists for the update.

Comment: I don't recommend hand-rolling your own lists. Just use enumitem to make a better `itemize`.

Comment: @Will: absolutely. Not ideal. I just provided the best answer I could given my available knowledge. I was unfamiliar with the enumitem package, but perhaps you could provide an example with that method that also accomplishes the above?

Answer (score 7):

Add `\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}` to the `list` parameters. You could also use the [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package which offers a `nolistsep` option for the list environments.