# How to reduce vertical space itemize environment inside table

Tags: itemize, enumitem

I have this:

[image]

I want for the first item to be vertically aligned with my other cells.  How can I do it?  The answers provided here suggested to play with `topsep` and `partopsep`:

[How can I change behaviour of enumitem?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35475/how-can-i-change-behaviour-of-enumitem/35476#35476)

[How to get rid of vertical space before and behind the lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5587/how-to-get-rid-of-vertical-space-before-and-behind-the-lists/5589#5589)

[How to reduce space after the end of a tabbing environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/how-to-reduce-space-after-the-end-of-a-tabbing-environment/3158#3158)

But as you can see in my code, it has no effect:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}                                  
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}                              
\usepackage{tabularx}                               

\begin{document}


\begin{table}\small
\centering
    \caption{Summary of proven determinants for falling}
    \label{tab:FallPredictionVariables}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcY}
        \textbf{Author} &\textbf{Subject count (M:F)} & \centering\arraybackslash\textbf{Determinants}\\
        \firsthline\\

        ? &
        311 (?) &
        \begin{itemize}[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
            \item Posture sway
            \item Two or more falls in previous year
            \item Low hand grip strength
            \item Depressive state of mind
        \end{itemize}\\\\       
        \lasthline\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

As mentioned in the past questions, I know it is possible to use `\setitemize`, but I don't want to set this globally, just locally for this table.

Answer (score 10):

[image]

In practice I would add `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}` to give a bit of space under the lines.

Never use `\\` after `\hline` it will do the wrong thing.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}                                  
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}                              
\usepackage{tabularx}                               

\begin{document}


\begin{table}\small
\centering
    \caption{Summary of proven determinants for falling}
    \label{tab:FallPredictionVariables}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcY}
        \textbf{Author} &\textbf{Subject count (M:F)} & \centering\arraybackslash\textbf{Determinants}\\
        \firsthline
        ? &
        311 (?) &\mbox{}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
        \begin{itemize}[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
            \item Posture sway
            \item Two or more falls in previous year
            \item Low hand grip strength
            \item Depressive state of mind
        \end{itemize}\\
        \lasthline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where would you write the `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}`?  Is this definition just local?

Comment: `\setlength` is always a local definition so set in in the preamble to affect all tables in the document or after `\begin{table}` and before `\begin{tabular}` to affect just this one.

Comment: Will this affect just the first space between `\firsthline` and the first data row or will it affect all spaces between rows, like `arraystrech` does?

Answer (score 7):

There were two problems I found.  One is that you don't want to use a `\\` after `\firsthline`.  That's what added the initial extra row.  But also, the itemize environment wants to add that initial space, which Stefan Kottwitz shows how to avoid by putting the itemize into a minipage ([Preventing itemize environment to insert initial vertical space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/preventing-itemize-environment-to-insert-initial-vertical-space)).

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}                                  
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}                              
\usepackage{tabularx}                               
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{table}\small
\centering
    \caption{Summary of proven determinants for falling}
    \label{tab:FallPredictionVariables}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\compress\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcY}
        \textbf{Author} &\textbf{Subject count (M:F)} & \centering\arraybackslash\textbf{Determinants}\\
        \firsthline

        ? &
        311 (?) &
        \begin{itemize}[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
            \item Posture sway
            \item Two or more falls in previous year
            \item Low hand grip strength
            \item Depressive state of mind
        \end{itemize}\\\\    
        \lasthline\\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any ideas on how to give a little extra room after the `\firsthline`?

Comment: @MarioS.E. `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` after the `\begin{table}` will do it.  This is what David Carlisle also mentioned in his solution.