# How do I remove white space above itemize command in beamer using enumitem

Tags: beamer, spacing, itemize, enumitem

I am new to \LaTeX. I am trying to use solution give on [How to remove the whitespace BEFORE itemize/enumerate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86054/how-to-remove-the-whitespace-before-itemize-enumerate)
to remove vertical space before itemize environment using enumitem and beamer. But I don't get the desired result. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  Maybe this will help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114280/how-to-reduce-vertical-space-itemize-environment-inside-table

Comment: In my case (beamer with some customization) I also needed in Gonzalo Medina's answer: \setlength\parskip{0pt} (I don't have enough rep to comment.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's *not* a good idea to use the `enumitem` package with `beamer` since `beamer` has its own ways of dealing with the standard list-like environments. Just by loading `enumitem` when using `beamer` you loose the special `beamer` formatting and the overlay-awareness of the list-like components.

To suppress the spacing, you can redefine `itemize` as implemented by `beamer` in the file `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`. In the following example I show a possible modification, setting `\topsep`, `\partopsep` and `\itemsep` to `0pt` (adjust these values according to your needs); the modified lines are signaled with `%NEW`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
      {%
        \setlength\topsep{0pt}%NEW
        \setlength\partopsep{0pt}%NEW
        \setlength\itemsep{0pt}%NEW
        \def\makelabel##1{%
          {%
            \hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
          }%
        }%
      }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright%
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text
\begin{itemize}
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\partopsep{0pt}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
\end{itemize}
Some text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for comparison, the same list without the modifications:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: Is there a way of doing this locally? Say I want to do this for one and only one list?

Comment: @user1729 Sure. The redefinition can be made inside a group to keep its effect local. Comments are not the place to give code, so if you want to, feel free to open a nee question.

Comment: This does sadly not work for me.

Comment: Works like a charm. I don't know much of the code, but just wonder why we need so much code to adjust the padding/margin? Also can we limit the scope to a single frame?

Comment: \setlength\topsep{0pt}
 inside itemize environment removed the space before, without importing enuitem package which creates conflict with beamer

Answer (score -2):

As described in the `enumitem` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf), you have two parameters to play with regarding vertical top space: `topsep` and `partopsep`.

So, for example, writing this:

```
\begin{enumerate}[topsep={0pt},partopsep={0pt}]
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
```

Will produce something like this:

[image]

Of course, if you want to play with the separation between items, you can do so by setting `itemsep`, again, as described in the `enumitem` documentation (available at the link mentioned above).

Comment: But it doesn't work with beamer